# KDE keyboard repeat delay/rate settings don't work/have no effect?

Tags: debian, x11, kde, keyboard, plasma5

How can I get the KDE (Plasma 5.8.6 on Debian Stretch) System Settings for keyboard repeat & delay to actually do something?

These settings:

[image: KDE Keyboard settings screenshot]

Whenever I change and apply the settings I don't see any effect on the X11 repeat/delay state (as seen via `xset q | grep "auto repeat delay"`).

Comment: This is a [known bug with Wayland](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410626).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Startup and Shutdown → Background Services configuration applet,
make sure the Keyboard Daemon service ("Enables switching keyboard layout through shortcuts or system tray") is checked and in the "Running" state:

[image: Keyboard Daemon service screenshot]

If this does not seem to have an effect, log out and back in. The settings should be applied afterwards.

For whatever reason this service is *also* responsible for propagating rate/delay changes to X11, which you can see live via:

```
watch -n1 'xset q | grep "auto repeat delay"'
```

Source: [bcooksley's post at KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=108549#p254371).

Comment: +1 but for me this service was stopped, and the keyboard repeat still worked. However, the repeat stopped randomly at one point. It was enough for me to toggle this service to get it working again.

Comment: It  is running for me. But even restarting it had no effect. Restarting the computer applied the settings, though.

Comment: It was on for me, but disabling it, re-enabling it, then logging out/in finally applied my settings. Kind of annoying because I cannot test the settings without having to restart. Guess I'll file a bug report with KDE.

Comment: same thing as @Albert. It's running, but no effect. Can wait until restart or set this settings manually. From `xset` help: `r rate [delay [rate]]`
`xset r rate 150 25`

Comment: This may be a [bug with Wayland](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410626). The `xset r rate 250 25` workaround worked without needing logging out/in.